# how to build a select tag from a range in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have a drop down that consists of values 10% 20% 30% so on till 100.

In ruby It can be done by

```
(10..100).step(10) { |i| p i }
```

how can i convert this into a select tag?

I tried:

```
<%=p.select :thc, options_for_select((10..100).step(10) {|s| ["#{s}%", s]})%>
```

but this is printing `10 11 12 13....100`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
<%=p.select :thc, options_for_select((10..100).step(10).to_a.map{|s| ["#{s}%", s]})%>
```

Comment: You actually don't need the .to_a, but you did forget the .map method before your braces.

Comment: Could you explain me why ["#{s}%", s] not simply "#{s}%". I ran onto that question while solving similar problem and that helped me a lot but I can't understand why ", s" is needed (without it it works as well)...

Comment: A few years ago so I might be remembering it wrong. But since it's a select tag it requires a label/value pair (where value is inferred from label if it's missing). `["#{s}%", s]` is actually returning an array in `["label", value]` format which creates the `<option value="value">label</option>` tag, while returning only `"#{s}%"` would mean it only returns the label, which creates the tag as `<option value="label">label</option>`

Answer (score 4):

`#step` returns an enumerator (or yields, as you've shown). It looks like what you want is to call `#collect` on this enumerator.

`<%=p.select :thc, options_for_select((10..100).step(10).collect {|s| ["#{s}%", s]})%>`

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= select("sale", "discount", (10..100).step(10).collect {|p| [ "#{p}%", p ] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Without Providing a Formatted Value.

If you landed here, like me, without the need to use `step()` or to provide a formatted value (e.g. "20%"), this is a nice and succinct method:

```
<%= f.select :year, (2011..Date.today.year).to_a %>

<select id="report_year" name="report[year]">
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

**With a Default**

```
<%= f.select :year, options_for_select( (2011..Date.today.year).to_a, Date.today.year ) %>

<select id="report_year" name="report[year]">
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I love trying to upvote only to discover that it's your answer from the past.