# rails select in fields_for, counting numbers to a value in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to print from a value in the model and showing a list of "multiple" selectable selections.

```
        <%= f.fields_for :blackwhite do |blackwhite| %>
          <div class="span6"><p class="muted text-right">Black and White</p></div>
          <%= blackwhite.select :newpage, options_for_select((1..number_of_images_entry).to_a), { :multiple => true } ) %>
        <% end %>
```

and don't quite understand

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=6716

I wanted to get the value from the prints table (current view) for "number_of_images_entry" column which has the integer value to count to, starting from 1. - i'm using an example here:

[how to build a select tag from a range in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239499/how-to-build-a-select-tag-from-a-range-in-rails)

:newpage is a column in the "blackwhite" table. (which is another table)

Thanks!

EDIT:

The code is getting values from the database now, but multiselect doesn't work.

```
 <%= blackwhite.select :newpage, options_for_select((1..(@print.number_of_images_entry)).to_a), { :multiple => true }  %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct your code.

```
 <%= blackwhite.select :newpages, options_for_select((1..(@print.number_of_images_entry)).to_a), {} ,multiple: true   %>
```

Comment: code is getting data to count from the database but is multiple selects is not working.